# Single quotes (') is replaced by &amp;apos;

Tags: html, xml, svg

I am using a third party jar file to generate svg file. I am expecting something like `myfunction('divId');` But output is coming as `myfunction(&amp;apos;divId&amp;apos;);` Is there any way to avoid `&amp;apos;`.

Comment: Output of what exactly?

Comment: Sounds like your output is htmlencoded. Turn that off. Or, htmldecode on your end.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Java (`jar` file), you could call [String#replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) like so -

```
String str = "myfunction(&amp;apos;divId&amp;apos;);";
str = str.replace("&amp;apos;", "'");
System.out.println(str);
```

Outputs

```
myfunction('divId');
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try defining a character set (i.e., `<meta charset="UTF-8">`) in your document header.

Answer (score 0):

&apos and &amp are not in the list of HTML4 entities, use &#39 instead.

```html
myfunction(&#39divid&#39)
```

should work.